# How to sort and store real time CAN-Bus data (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, storage, real-time, can-bus

I am currently working on a project that involves taking a car's CAN-Bus data, sorting the data, decoding the data, and then displaying the output. I am currently using Pandas to put the data into a list and sort it, however, I have run into a couple of problems that I will explain below.

**-Goal-**

As mentioned above, the goal of the code is to take in the CAN-Bus data of the car, sort the data by its CAN ID, take the bytes, decode them, and display them. A couple of problems arise from this.

1. The Can data comes in every 1/10th of a second, this can be changed to be either slower or faster.

2. In the code I'm using, the data is stored in the variable "receive". I haven't found a way for pandas to take the data from a variable and directly put it into a data frame, only put it into a CVS file and read from that file. I'm worried that having the code print to a CVS file and read from it in the next line takes unnecessary processing power.

3. When "receive" is printed out, all the data gets put into one line. This requires me to use the following code to only get the data needed.

Example of the Data in the variable "receive":

```
Timestamp: 1646874440.563719        ID: 0060    S Rx                DL:  8    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.563959        ID: 0090    S Rx                DL:  8    00 00 c2 00 61 83 00 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1646874440.564195        ID: 00c0    S Rx                DL:  8    00 2d 61 27 50 00 39 f3     Channel: can0
```

Code used to simplify:

```
df = pd.read_table("CB.txt", sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["a","Timestamp","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","ID","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","fag","9","10","11","B0","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","20","21","22","23","24","Channel"]
df = df.drop(columns=['a','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','fag','7','9','10','11','20','21','22','23','24'])   
print(df)

#OUTPUT

        Timestamp    ID  B0  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7 Channel
0    1.646874e+09  0060  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  08    can0
1    1.646874e+09  0090  00  00  c2  00  61  83  00  00    can0
2    1.646874e+09  00c0  00  2d  61  27  50  00  39  f3    can0
```

I am well aware of how poorly coded the data frame is, however it worked and I moved on from there. If there's a way to get rid of the whitespace then put it into a data frame then im game for it.

I then coded in a system to isolate the RPM ID shown in the code below.

```
for i in range(0, 1, 1):
    RPMID = df.loc[df['ID'] == '0090']
    rpmb0 = (RPMID['B0'])
    rpmb1 = (RPMID['B1'])
    rpmb2 = (RPMID['B2'])
    rpmb3 = (RPMID['B3'])
    rpmb4 = (RPMID['B4'])
    rpmb5 = (RPMID['B5'])
    rpmb6 = (RPMID['B6'])
    rpmb7 = (RPMID['B7'])
R = RPMID['B3'].apply(int, base=16)
P = RPMID['B4'].apply(int, base=16)
RPM = (P*256+R)/4
```

This code did succeed in isolating the RPM ID, storing the bytes of data, changing them from hex to decimal, and then solving the data for RPM. However, from here I don't know how to achieve the rest of the goals. The data comes in real-time, so the code has to run constantly in order to receive and sort the data accordingly. I need an extra system to store the RPM and the time frame to be used afterward. Since the data accumulates rather quickly, there might have to be a system to clear the data frame if it gets to big.

I am rather new to coding in python and working with CAN-Bus data, as well as storing and accessing data. I am looking for any kind of guidance as to how I should approach this problem, any kind of input helps. I don't specifically have to use pandas, this is the library that was recommended to me by a friend.

Thank you all for your time!

Summary:

- Code for storing and updating variables value.

- Code for splitting the data into columns.

- Code for isolating specific ID's.

- Code for extracting the bytes of data, translating them from hex to decimal.

- Code for storing the decoded data along with its timestamp.

- (POTENTIALLY) Code for clearing the data frame if it gets too big.

Code im using to receive the data:

```
def run():
    cmd = "mkdir -p {}".format(memory_folder)
    os.system(cmd)
    cmd = "mount -t tmpfs -o size={},mode=0755 tmpfs {}".format(memory_folder_size, memory_folder)
    os.system(cmd)

    message = "Running ChupaCarBrah..."
    _output_message(message)

    os.system("ip link set {can_interface} up type can bitrate {bitrate}".format(can_interface=can_interface, bitrate=bitrate))
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("ifconfig {can_interface} up".format(can_interface=can_interface))
    time.sleep(2)

    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel=can_interface, bitrate=bitrate)

   # hologram_network_connect()

    start = time.time()

    try:
        os.remove(stop_file)
    except OSError:
        pass

    speed = -1
    rpm = -1
    intake_air_temperature = -1
    while 1:
        csv_file_path = base_dir + os.sep + obd2_csv_file
        with open(csv_file_path, mode='r') as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            if os.path.isfile(stop_file):
                break
            for row in reader:
                service_id = -1
                pid = -1
                description = ""
                formula=""
                enabled = False
                if "Enabled" in row:
                    enabled = bool(int(row["Enabled"]))
                if enabled:
                    if "Mode (hex)" in row:
                        service_id = row["Mode (hex)"]
                        service_int = int(service_id, 16)
                    if "PID (hex)" in row:
                        pid = row["PID (hex)"]
                        pid_int = int(pid, 16)
                    if "Description" in row:
                        description = row["Description"]
                    if "Formula" in row:
                        formula = row["Formula"]
                        print(pid_int)

                    if service_int >= 0 and pid_int >= 0:
                        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x7DF, data=[2, service_int, pid_int, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], is_extended_id=False)

                        try:
                            bus.send(msg)
                            time.sleep(0.05)
                            for i in range(0, 1):
                                time.sleep(0.05)
                                receive = bus.recv(timeout=2)
                                if not receive:
                                    message = "No response from CAN bus. Service: {} PID: {} - {}".format(service_id.zfill(2), pid.zfill(2), description)
                                    _output_message(message)
                                    break
                                if len(response.data) == 8:
                                    responsebit = receive 
                                    print(responsebit) #try responsebit.data as well
                                    received_pid = list(responsebit.data)[0]
                                    A = list(responsebit.data)[1]
                                    B = list(responsebit.data)[2]
                                    C = list(responsebit.data)[3]
                                    D = list(responsebit.data)[4]
                                    E = list(responsebit.data)[5]
                                    F = list(responsebit.data)[6]
                                    G = list(responsebit.data)[7]
                                    
                                    #if service_id == "1":
                                        #if len(formula) > 0:
                                            #try:
                                               # result = eval(formula)
                                                #message = "{description}: {result}".format(description=description, result=result)
                                                #_output_message(message)
                                                #if pid_int == int(received_pid):
                                                 #   if pid_int == int("0C", 16):
                                                  #      rpm = result
                                                  #  if pid_int == int("0D", 16):
                                                   #     speed = result
                                                    #if pid_int == int("0F", 16):
                                                    #    intake_air_temperature = result
                                            #except:
                                             #   _output_message("Unable to parse formula: {}.".format(formula))
                                    #if service_id == "9":
                                        #result = ""
                                        #try:
                                         #   for c in list(response.data)[-3:]:
                                          #      result += chr(c)
                                           # message = "{description}: {result}".format(description=description, result=result)
                                            #_output_message(message)
                                        ##except:
                                          #  _output_message("Unable to parse response: {}.".format(response.data))
                        except can.CanError:
                            _output_message("CAN error")

            end = time.time()
            hours, rem = divmod(end - start, 3600)
            minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
            if minutes >= exfiltrate_interval:
                car_uuid = _get_car_uuid()
                timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())
               # gps_data = _read_gps_data()
                log = {"timestamp": timestamp, "GPS": gps_data, "speed": speed, "rpm": rpm, "temperature": intake_air_temperature}
                data = {"car_uuid": car_uuid, "log": log}
                if exfiltrate_data(data):
                    start = time.time()


    hologram_network_disconnect()
    bus.shutdown()
    os.system("ifconfig {can_interface} down".format(can_interface=can_interface))
    try:
        os.remove(stop_file)
    except OSError:
        pass
    message = "ChupaCarBrah exited successfully."
    _output_message(message)
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: What is your variable `receive`? A JSON? A string? Hard to say how to pass these values to pandas without knowing what they are.

Comment: @ibmx Didn't even think of that, I don't really know the answer myself as I am a beginner. I added the data receiving code to the post. The receive variable is found about halfway through. receive = bus.recv(timeout=2)